# Android activity.onCreateOptionsMenu itemMenu does not support addEventListener

Tags: android, android-activity, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I think it's a bug, I have opened a jira ticket.

```
var activity = win.getActivity();
    // Re-create Menu
    if(activity){
        activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e){
                var item, menu;
                menu = e.menu;
                menu.clear();
            var menuItem = menu.add({
              visible: true,
              title: 'title1',
              showAsAction : Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
            });
            var menuItem2 = menu.add({
              title : "title2",
              visible: true,
              showAsAction : Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
            });  
            menuItem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    console.log("aaaaa");
            });
            activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        };
    }
```

- [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [158,158]     menuItem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
- [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:              ^
- [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: TypeError: menuItem.addEventListener is not a function
- [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler:     at Activity.activity.onCreateOptionsMenu (eval at Module._compile (/app.js:728:13), :404:14)
- [ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at undefined:404: Uncaught TypeError: menuItem.addEventListener is not a function

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5997

Comment: working fine on my Android 7.0.1 phone with Ti SDK 7.4.1. Did you place this code in the `open` event of the window? If not: do it :)

Comment: Yes, I have done it :(

Comment: ok, you didn't mention that in the example above. Olease add your SDK version, phone/emulator version.

Comment: Ok, after reboot all works! :-/

Comment: It's not a bug with what it seems. It's a bug with LiveView. You are using the LiveView while testing that code and it will work only in first few sessions while LiveView is enabled, but after few runs, it will start throwing that error.